# Is it true that PRIMES are in SPARSE?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, primes

I'm wondering if **PRIMES**, the language of all prime numbers represented in binary, which is $\{10, 11, 101, 111, 1011, 1101, ...\}$, belongs to the **SPARSE** class, a set of all sparse languages, that is, languages satisfying the property that the amount of words of length $n$ is bounded by some polynomial $p(n)$.

I believe the answer should be yes, because as the size of the tested number $p$ grows, the  size of its binary representation grows logarithmically while the density of primes logarithmically shrinks, which leads me to an assumption that $p(n)$ could even be a constant, but I found no resources online to support or contradict this opinion.

Comment: Please check your maths. You found two "logarithms" that are quite unrelated. The number of primes less than 10^18 is 24,739,954,287,740,860. That's most of the primes fitting into 60 bits.

Comment: Hmm, true. Let me think about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there are $\Theta(\frac{n}{\log(n)})$ primes between $n$ and $2n$. Sum them up to get the number of primes up to $2n$, and then we know that $2n$ has $\log(n)+1$ bits. I think if you do the maths it will not end up in $SPARSE$, but I might be wrong here.

Comment: I see the error of my ways. When splitting numbers into intervals from $n$ to $2n$, which are the numbers of equal binary length, $n$ grows exponentially, so $\mathcal{\Theta}(\frac{n}{log(n)})$ becomes $\frac{2^n}{log(2^n)} = \frac{2^n}{n}$. That means, for a specific binary length, there are linearly ($cn$ times) many more numbers than prime numbers as the binary length grows.